# GRPC client with multiple endpoints

Tags: node.js, grpc

I am writing a Node.js Grpc client for a service which exposes 2 endpoints, for ex: `localhost:50051, localhost:50052` . I want to be able to retry on `localhost:50052` if the request fails on `localhost:50051`.

One way I can think of achieving this is by creating 2 separate clients. However, I was wondering if there is a way to achieve this by just creating a single client, for ex: `new test_proto.test(['localhost:50051', 'localhost:50052'],grpc.credentials.createInsecure());`

I tried looking for an answer in the various wiki pages and issues on Github but I couldn't.

Any suggestion would be of great help, Thanks !

Comment: AFAIK there is no built-in logic in grpc. There is a recent article on loadbalancing, though: https://grpc.io/blog/loadbalancing
It basically states - for your problem - that you have to handle all the logic by yourself.

Comment: thanks @DominikSandjaja , that's what I suspected. I just wanted to check if there was a hidden feature which has not been documented yet.

Comment: As an update to this comment, the article has been moved to https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-load-balancing/